# Overloading operator[] in C++, but to prevent a[i]=one_special_specific_value

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am implementing Spare Vector ADT, and want to overload operator[].
I have a list of pair of int and double. I want to create new Node(5, 3.5) by e.g. a[5]=3.5, but I want to make it impossible to assign 0 value to one of the node, since it should be a Spare Vector, so by a[7]=0 no new Node should be created. How can I implement function double& operator to do so?

UPD, thank you guys, I do it on my own, but your ideas about proxy is what I was looking for.

```
public:

    proxy(ListMap<T> *v, unsigned int i) : vec(v), index(i), dump(T()) { }

    ListMap<T> *vec;

    const unsigned int& index;

    T dump;

    T& operator=(T o)
    {
        if(o==0)
        {
            return dump;
        }
        return vec->operator[](index);
    }

    operator T()
    {
        return vec->operator[](index);
    }
```

Comment: sparse array?  Try proxy objects or 'fake' references mayhap.

Comment: Define "prevent". What exactly should happen when someone does pass the value 0?

Comment: @delnan, for example nothing should happen there

Comment: @Yakk Could you tell me more about how to use proxy in this situation?

Comment: Are you sure you want to prevent statements of that form? Wouldn't it be better to allow them, but then have the implementation treat them separately?

Comment: as signature of the `operator[]` normally returns a reference to a type. the `operator[]` is never passed the right hand value, only the index.  It will be better to implement a method in `Spare Vector`, `int addNode(int index, double value);` and indicate via the return value where addNode passed or failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
a[i] = b;
```

involves two operators: `operator[]` and `operator=`.

For your purpose, you need a helper type, returned by `operator[]`, implementing `operator=`:

```
class item_helper
{
public:
    item_helper(spare_vector* vector, int index)
      : m_vector(vector), m_index(index)
    {
    }

    // Conversion operator to double.
    // Called when using as an r-value, e.g. for b = a[i]
    operator double()
    {
        return m_vector->get_item(m_index);
    }

    item_helper& operator=(double value)
    {
        // forward to the vector
        m_vector->set_item(m_index, value);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    spare_vector* m_vector;
    int m_index;
};

class spare_vector
{
public:
    // Instead of a double, we return an item_helper, that can be
    // converted to double, and invokes special logic when assigned
    // a double.
    item_helper operator[](int index)
    {
        return item_helper(this, index);
    }

    double get(int index)
    {
        // return a value by index
    }

    void set_item(int index, double value)
    {
        // create your new node, handle the special case if "value" is zero
    }
};
```

If you want to hide the `get_item` and `set_item` methods, make them private, and make `item_helper` a friend of `spare_vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the `[]` operator of a std::vector indeed but this cannot help you in filtering unwanted rvalues.

If you take the operator[] signature you will notice that it takes a single argument - the index -.

It will be something like this for a std::vector< double> implementation

> double& operator[]( size_t index );

What the operator will do here is allocating a new double to the corresponding index - if it doesn't exist yet - and return a non-const reference which will be assigned to the rvalue (potentially 0 in your case).

Therefore it is NOT in the [] operator that you can implement a filtering logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a subscript operator which yields a proxy and, upon access 
of the proxy, decides to insert/erase the internal value as needed. I would, however, fully expect that you are much better off to filter zero values before the reach the subscript operator.

Here is roughly how the proxy could look like:

```
struct proxy {
    Cont*   cont;
    int        index;
    double value;
    proxy(Cont* cont, int index)
        : cont(cont);
        , index(index)
    {}
    operator double() const { 
        return cont->get(index);
    }
    void operator= (double v) {
        if (v) {
            cont->set(index, v);
        }
        // else remove entry?
    }
};

proxy Cont::operator[](int index) {
    return proxy(this, index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a toy proxy object:

```
template<typename T>
struct toy_proxy {
  std::function<void(T const&)> m_set;
  std::function<T()> m_get;

  T Get() const { return m_get(); }

  toy_proxy<T>& operator=(T const& o) {
    m_set(o);
    return *this;
  }
  operator T() const { return m_get(); }
  toy_proxy( std::function<void(T const&)> set, std::function<T(void)> get ):m_set(set), m_get(get) {}
  toy_proxy& operator=( toy_proxy<T> const& o ) {
    m_set( o );
    return *this;
  }
};
#define RETURNS(X) ->decltype(X) { return (X); }
#define TOY_OPERATOR(OP) \
template<typename U, typename T> \
auto operator OP( toy_proxy<U> const& lhs, T const& rhs ) \
  RETURNS( lhs.Get() OP rhs ) \
template<typename U, typename T> \
auto operator OP( U const& lhs, toy_proxy<T> const& rhs ) \
  RETURNS( lhs OP rhs.Get() ) \
template<typename U, typename T> \
auto operator OP( toy_proxy<U> const& lhs, toy_proxy<T> const& rhs ) \
  RETURNS( lhs OP rhs.Get() )
TOY_OPERATOR(+)
TOY_OPERATOR(*)
TOY_OPERATOR(-)
TOY_OPERATOR(/)
TOY_OPERATOR(%)
TOY_OPERATOR(^)
TOY_OPERATOR(|)
TOY_OPERATOR(&)
TOY_OPERATOR(||)
TOY_OPERATOR(&&)
TOY_OPERATOR(<)
TOY_OPERATOR(>)
TOY_OPERATOR(<=)
TOY_OPERATOR(>=)
TOY_OPERATOR(!=)
TOY_OPERATOR(==)
#undef TOY_OPERATOR
#define TOY_MONO_OPERATOR(OP) \
template<typename T> \
auto operator OP( toy_proxy<T> const& proxy ) \
  RETURNS( OP proxy.Get() )
TOY_MONO_OPERATOR(*)
TOY_MONO_OPERATOR(!)
TOY_MONO_OPERATOR(~)
#undef TOY_MONO_OPERATOR
```

which is missing `->`, `++` and `--` and probably a few others I couldn't be bothered to write.

Also, a real proxy object wouldn't use a `std::function`, but probably some anonymous lambda objects.

The goal is to create a proxy object that is "as close to" being a reference-to-`T` as you can practically do, given that your `T` might not actually exist.  Assignment and implicit-conversion-to-`T` do most of the heavy lifting (note that implicit-conversion-to-anything-that-`T`-can-be-implicitly-converted-to might be even better).